# Inserting key, value pairs to empty dict via assignment operator

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm working my way through the MIT 6.00 class on OpenCourseWare and don't quite understand a bit of code I've run into.

```
def deal_hand(n):
    """
    Returns a random hand containing n lowercase letters.
    At least n/3 the letters in the hand should be VOWELS.

    Hands are represented as dictionaries. The keys are
    letters and the values are the number of times the
    particular letter is repeated in that hand.

    n: int >= 0
    returns: dictionary (string -> int)
    """
    hand={}
    num_vowels = n / 3

    for i in range(num_vowels):
        x = VOWELS[random.randrange(0,len(VOWELS))]
        hand[x] = hand.get(x, 0) + 1

    for i in range(num_vowels, n):    
        x = CONSONANTS[random.randrange(0,len(CONSONANTS))]
        hand[x] = hand.get(x, 0) + 1

    return hand
```

My question is about `hand[x] = hand.get(x, 0) + 1`.

I understand that this looks up the value associated with a key (the key being either a vowel or consonant taken from a string initiated earlier in the script) and then adds 1 to it.

My question is how Python can look for the value associated with `hand[x]` when it doesn't actually exist yet. When python gets to `hand[x] = hand.get(x, 0) + 1` how does it assign a new value to a key that never existed to begin with (i.e. `hand[x]`)?

Comment: Hint: what is the purpose of the second argument of `get`?

Comment: in `hand.get(x, 0)` zero is the default argument, so if it gets the value, but it doesnt exist, it returns zero and then 1 is added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .get() method has an optional second parameter, specifying a default if it doesn't exist it. In this case it returns a 0 if the key x doesn't exist.

Comment: I understand that part. I don't think I was very clear about my question, let me try again. How is the key x (in this case some letter) inserted into the dictionary? If I have any given empty dictionary can I add elements to it simply by saying `dict['new key'] = 'new value'`?